# How collect metrics from uwsgi with help collectd

Tags: docker, uwsgi, collectd

Good afternoon, good people. Help me find the right solution. In one docker container Launched uwsgi application. In another docker container  launched collector  metrics - collectd , who collects metrics and sends them to the server  -openstdb. 
The question how do I do that would be received collectd metrics from uwsgi. I understand, is necessary start with uwsgi option "--enable-metrics" and maybe add "--stats-push statsd:address[,prefix]". and into config collectd add plugin .
But how all this tie in practice do not understand. 
Grateful for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was as follows.
Run uwsgi with param.Below content config.ini

```
[uwsgi]
plugin = stats_pusher_statsd
enable-metrics = true
stats-push = statsd:collectd:8125
```

And in collectd add pluggin

```
<Plugin statsd>
  Host "::"
  Port "8125"
  DeleteSets false
</Plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be default stats_pusher_statsd is not enabled so if you build uwsgi from src code.

Edit buildconf/default.ini

```
main_plugin = python,gevent,stats_pusher_statsd
inherit = base
```

And then run `python uwsgiconfig.py --build` as it said in the official document [Installing from source](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Install.html)